# How to filter a table and display only <td> values than <tr> values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, tablesorter

Am working on a simple html application which has a table grid data.

Consider the sample data as follows.

```
no  name  department
1   abc   IT
2   def   CSE
```

Consider I have a search box which will get a search key and display a filtered table view.

A lot of jquery tables allow me to implement the search logic as follows:

Say if I give the search key as 'abc' it will show the filtered table as follows

```
no name department
1  abc  IT
```

In the above case, it displays the entire row specific to 'abc' and the same entire row will get displayed when I give 'IT' or '1' as well.

My question is...

Rather than displaying filtered rows with matching searchkey I want to display only the filtered cells with matching search key as follows:

Say if I give the search key as 'abc' it should show the filtered table as follows:

```
name
abc
```

You can find an equivalent Jsfiddle worked out example over [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cnvrP/6/)

Comment: Pretty bad idea. You can do it, it's very easy. however this will lead to confusing UX. Say you filter by word "9". It filters 7 rows, one of which matches "ID" column, and other "Points" column. With your approach your table results become confusing as you can't distinguish those data columns.

Comment: I got your point which is very valid but my intention was to display filtered information than distinguishing

Comment: Btw display:None would do it too

Answer (score 2):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/cnvrP/12/    (firefox)
**HTML**

```
    <input id="searchkey">
    <div id="maindiv">

<table id="mytble">
    <tr>
        <th>no</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>department</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>IT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>CSE</td>n
    </tr>
</table>
        <div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
var $mytbl;
var found = false;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $mytbl = $('#mytble').clone();
    $("#searchkey").keyup(function () {
        found = false;
        var key = $(this).val();
        search(key);
    });
});

        function search(key) {
            $mytbl.find('td').each(function (i, v) {
                if (key && $(v).html().contains(key)) {
                    var $th = $mytbl.find('th').eq($(v).index());
                    var $tbl = $('<table />');
                    $tbl.append('<tr><th>' + $th.html() + '</th></tr>');
                    $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + $(v).html() + '</td></tr>');

                    $('#mytble').html('');
                    $('#mytble').html($tbl.html());
                    found = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (!found) {
                        if (!key) {
                            $('#mytble').html('');
                            $('#mytble').html($mytbl.html());
                        }
                        else {
                            var $tbl = $('<table />');
                            $tbl.append('<tr><th>' + 'Result' + '</th></tr>');
                            $tbl.append('<tr><td>' + 'No matching records found' + '</td></tr>');

                            $('#mytble').html('');
                            $('#mytble').html($tbl.html());
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
department
IT
```

Comment: In the jsfiddle example I shared.. There is no appending of table elements to the body...the existing table will get filtered and displayed. Is there a workaround to acheive the similar experience?.

Like on entering 'cs' in the search box for key down event.. I need to display the corresponding <td> value but in your case only 'cse' filters it and moreover new table is created

Comment: Thanks for the quick support. I have modified your code over here[link](http://jsfiddle.net/cnvrP/10/). But as per my fiddle in the question I would like to reconstruct the previous table when I remove the search key from the text box. In your example if I give the key as 'I' it wont return the elements starting with 'I' also. Please check the fiddle in my question..it does the filtering on keytype (i.e) Keydown and hence when removing the key the table is reconstruted

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Put this script in the "head" part:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
            var val = $(this).val();
            $("#searchTable tr:first th").hide();
            $("#searchTable tr td").each(function (i) {
                var content = $(this).text();
                if (content.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) == -1) {
                    $(this).hide();
                } else {
                    var l = $(this).index();
                    $(this).show();
                    $(this).parents("table").find("tr:first th:eq(" + l + ")").show();

                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Lets suppose your html looks like:

```
   <div>
        <input type="text" id="searchInput" />
        <table id="searchTable">
            <tr>
                <th>No</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Department</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>abc</td>
                <td>IT</td>
            </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>aaa</td>
                <td>School</td>
            </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>3</td>
                <td>bbb</td>
                <td>Payment</td>
            </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>ccc</td>
                <td>Account</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please let me know how can I select entire row matching the search term